# Issue With Selenium For Mobile Devices

Tags: java, python, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing an exception where I need to open a new window,but the new window is not opening in IOS or android devices.

which works perfectly fine in Chrome Ie and Firefox with Windows.

code

```
driver.get("http://testdroid.com/tech/the-basics-of-mobile-web-testing-using-appium-selenium");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Latest')]")).click();

String target="https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Platform+Configurator#/";
String value="testEnrollWindow";


String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle

String args1 = String.format("window.open('%s', '%s'); null;", target, value);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(args1);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
}

driver.close(); // close newly opened window when done with it
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle); // switch b
```

Comment: Mention exception. Probably the operation is not supported in your mobile driver

Comment: Am not getting any exception there but switching is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while running my tests on mobile devices. After many hit and trial, I find out that it was window sizing thats causing it.

So remove `driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: Even after i remove that code still am facing the same exception.if i print the getWindowHandles() am getting only 1 as output which is expected to be two.

Comment: Am even not seeing the exception but the opening of new window is not happening.